# Swift: How would I pass map pin data to a new VC?

Tags: ios, json, mapkit

I'm struggling with passing data from a map pin to a new vc.

**Scenario**

Map pin data (name, subtitle & coordinates) are currently being read from a JSON file. Map pins are dropped, when map pin has been clicked a new view will open and display the corresponding title and subtitle and some other data in labels in a new vc.

I've been following [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/90971/introduction-mapkit-swift-tutorial) for extracting data from a JSON file.

**Issue**:  I'm struggling to find a way to pass the data from the map pin to the labels.

I've done a previous project where I pass data from one textfield to a label.

Thank you very much!

**EDIT:**

I realised I didn't give any code.

**newFeatureVC**

```
// Callout accessory
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

    let identifier = "POIAnnotations"

    if annotation is POIAnnotations {
        var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier)
        if annotationView == nil {
            annotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
            annotationView!.canShowCallout = true
            let button = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
            annotationView!.rightCalloutAccessoryView = button
        }
        else {
            annotationView!.annotation = annotation
        }
        return annotationView
    }
    return nil
}

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {

    if control == view.rightCalloutAccessoryView {

        performSegue(withIdentifier: "showAnnotationInfo", sender: self)

    }
}

func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showAnnotationInfo" {

        let destViewController = segue.destination as! ShopDetailViewController
    }
}
```

**POIAnnotations**

This class is where variables stored for the name, subtitle and coordinates.

```
class POIAnnotations: NSObject, MKAnnotation {


var title: String?
var subtitle: String?
var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D

init(title:String, subtitle:String, coordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2D) {

    self.title = title
    self.subtitle = subtitle
    self.coordinate = coordinate

    super.init()
}

class func fromJSON(_ json: [JSONValue]) -> POIAnnotations? {
    // 1
    var title: String
    if let titleOrNil = json[1].string {
        title = titleOrNil
    } else {
        title = ""
    }
    var subtitle: String
    if let subtitleOrNil = json[2].string {
        subtitle = subtitleOrNil
    } else {
        subtitle = ""
    }

    // 2
    let latitude = (json[3].string! as NSString).doubleValue
    let longitude = (json[4].string! as NSString).doubleValue
    let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)

    // 3
    return POIAnnotations(title: title, subtitle: subtitle, coordinate: coordinate)
}
```

}

**SecondVC**

```
class ShopDetailViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var shopName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var shopRating: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var cancelButton: UIBarButtonItem!

var shopNameData = "name"
var shopRatingData = "rating"
```

What I've already tried doing is the same way that I got the data from the JSON file in the POIAnnotations class.

I tried calling the fromJSON function then tried storing it in variable to display on the label. But I couldn't get my head around how to do it.

Comment: Need to know what you're tried here.  Show some methods where you are passing data and explain one step at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Use MKMapViewDelegate method to detect which pin is tapped and then display its data in view controller.

```
func mapView(MKMapView, didSelect: MKAnnotationView)
```